# FireFox Extension does Script Injection to TinyMCE Editor

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, tinymce

One of my fire fox's extensions inject following script to TinyMCE Editor's contents.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdncache3-a.akamaihd.net/loaders/1032/l.js?aoi=1311798366&amp;pid=1032&amp;zoneid=62862"></script>
```

Have anyone ever experienced this? Please let me know how do I prevent this? I have removed that extension and found that script injection was stopped. I don't remember the exact name of the extension that I removed. Please let me know if you recognize it.

Comment: The script itself does not look malicious (though with all that code, it's hard to say for certain).

Comment: @arxanas: No, it isn't malicious - it injects advertising.

Comment: To someone who deduced my points, did I even mention that it is malicious? Even if it is not malicious, should I accept the condition that user's contents are being injected with such scripts? I feel my question is being treated as nonsense.

Comment: The issue is that you've solved your problem. Some extensions alter the DOM. There's not much to be done for it.

Comment: I don't think of removing extension as a solution. Telling users to check their browsers and remove extensions is not a solution. What I want to do is to prevent this kind of behavior from my web application. I hope there might be a way or two to filter script tags from TinyMCE Editor's contents. Anyway, thanks everyone.

Comment: @WladimirPalant an extension that injects advertising into input fields is malicious. Seeing as how I can't find the extension on Firefox's index anymore I'm guessing they found it malicious also.

Comment: @CodyCraven: Addons.mozilla.org has a policy that forbids extensions that inject advertisements into web pages - but this has nothing to do with "malicious" or not.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your question. I had the same problem with you,and I found the extension's name was "Videofiledownload - Download youtube video 1.5".